# The terminal doesn't display UTF-8 accents (C++17)

Tags: get, c++17, character, diacritics

The code below compiles without errors or warnings. When I run it, the terminal doesn’t display the accents that it should. For example, in the line "Você digitou: " (line 29). I believe both the terminal and the project are configured for UTF-8 encoding and UTF-8 without signature, respectively. I’m using Visual Studio Code 2022 and would like to know how to check this and if the code below should display accents. I’m a beginner, recently graduated in computer science, and it’s my first time using such a comprehensive and complex software like VSC. Thank you for everything.

[cpp code for download](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B68c7e49223dd4c6abd892d5bb7b878eb638277473933414806_Teste.cpp&tid=68c7e49223dd4c6abd892d5bb7b878eb638277473933414806)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> // Para utilizar _getch() e _kbhit()

int main() {
    char ch;

    do {
        std::string input;

        std::cout << "Digite uma string (ou pressione Esc para sair): ";

        while (true) {
            if (_kbhit()) {
                ch = _getch();

                if (ch == 27) { // Tecla Esc
                    break;
                }

                if (ch == 13) { // Tecla Enter
                    break;
                }

                input += ch;
                std::cout << ch;
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl << "Você digitou: " << input << std::endl;

    } while (ch != 27);

    std::cout << "Programa encerrado." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I tryed to run the code, I would like to know if the code is correct, if it's some configuration issue, or what it might be.
The result is:
[Terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfL41.png)